# activity tab shows weird compressed usercards

Tags: bug, profile-page, responses, activity

I think this screenshot of the responses tab of my profile's activity tab says it all.

[image]

Using a wide-screen monitor, fullscreen.
Firefox 68.4.2esr on macOS 10.14.6